# QML ListElement pass list of strings

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a `listview` who's delegate has a repeater in it which is supposed to be populated by text. If the repeater's model property is hard coded this way:

`model: ['String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3'];`

It works perfectly by showing 3 items in the repeater's region.
However, I want to send such a list using a `ListElement` and this is what I tried:

```
ListElement{
    shape: "Circle"; colors: ['Red', 'Blue'];
}
```

Unfortunately this approach doesn't work and throws an error:

> > ListElement: cannot use script for property value

How many I achieve this? TIA

Comment: What is the purpose for the list of colors? Is this list ("Red", "Blue") intended to be the actual colors for the list elements? Are you wanting the ListView to contain the actual strings "Red" and "Blue"?

Comment: @C.Korb Its just a vague example, original strings are different. Property names as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can't](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html):

> Values must be simple constants; either strings (quoted and optionally within a call to QT_TR_NOOP), boolean values (true, false), numbers, or enumeration values (such as AlignText.AlignHCenter).

The most powerful way to expose data to views is by creating a [C++ model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html).

However, if you really don't want to go to C++, you could store the colours in a comma-separated string, and then split them:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListView {
        width: 32
        height: 64
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement{
                shape: "Circle"
                colors: "red, blue"
            }
            ListElement{
                shape: "Square"
                colors: "green,yellow"
            }
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 32
            height: 32
            radius: shape === "Circle" ? width / 2 : 0

            property var colorArray: colors.split(",")

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop {
                    position: 0
                    color: colorArray[0]
                }
                GradientStop {
                    position: 1
                    color: colorArray[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I worked with this approach already but I was waiting for a better answer. Thanks! At least now I know I could call the split function directly on the variable declaration for the `model` property.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Mitch's answer would be to ditch the `ListModel` and use a plain Javascript array of objects as the model.

With that solution, you'll lose the dynamic features of the `ListModel` (adding, removing, inserting, ...). You also won't be able to use sections in your view or use a proxymodel on this model.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200

    ListView {
        width: 32
        height: 64
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: [
            {
                shape: "Circle",
                colors: ["red", "blue"]
            },
            {
                shape: "Square",
                colors: ["green", "yellow"]
            }
        ]
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 32
            height: 32
            radius: modelData.shape === "Circle" ? width / 2 : 0

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop {
                    position: 0
                    color: modelData.colors[0]
                }
                GradientStop {
                    position: 1
                    color: modelData.colors[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```