# Using GridView as a template object - How to set ListModel as an alias?

Tags: string, oop, gridview, qml, alias

I'm currently working on a large QML project, and I've come to a point where it would be advantageous to create what is essentially a template of a page, to which I can add as little information as possible in the definition of each page.

Currently, I have a MyPage.qml file, which defines objects such as the background mousearea and the elements which each page have in common such as a back button, but then I come to my problem - where not every page is alike.

The elements in each page are aligned in a grid.  Initially I had used rows and columns to organize those elements, but I've come under the impression that a GridView object would be more advantageous.

As it stands, here is my implementation:

```
Item {
//MyPage.qml
    id: page
    default property alias contentmodel: content.model

    ...

    GridView{
        id: content
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: parent.width/4
        cellHeight: parent.height/6
        focus: true
        model: contentmodel

        delegate: Item{
            height: content_background.height/6
            width: content_background.width/4

            property var entry: entries.split(",")

            MyComboBox{
                id: del_combo
                height: parent.height
                width: parent.width
                entries: entry
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is then instantiated from an actual page definition whose important features are:

```
MyPage {

    ...

    ListModel {
        id: contentmodel
        ListElement { entries: "string1,string2" }
        ListElement { entries: "string3,string4,string5,string6,string7" }

        ...

    }
}
```

In this manner, I aim to have different pages consisting of different combo boxes, pulling their similar code from the same source, and with minimal overlap.

Also worthy of note is the nature of "entries".  It is a string consisting of concatenated substrings, separated by commas, which is then split back into its component parts within MyPage.qml.  This is the same as recommended from [QML ListElement pass list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599271/qml-listelement-pass-list-of-strings)

MyPage.qml is having issues receiving this string, often only providing the first element to a MyComboBox object or none at all.

So my question to you is, where did I go wrong in this implementation?  Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach?  Are there alternatives to using aliasing?  Do you have any example code which is able to accomplish this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your first `...` when you instantiate `MyPage` for example?

Comment: Can you try to replace the 'default property' by 'property' and use the solution proposed below by @Blabbouze  I would also remove the "model: contentmodel"  in MyPage.qml

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a property `contentmodel` in `MyPage.qml`.

When using `MyPage`component you need to attribute your `ListModel` to the `contentmodel` property, not set your `ListModel` `id` to `contentmodel`.

This should work :

```
MyPage {
    contentmodel : ListModel {
        ListElement { entries: "string1,string2" }
        ListElement { entries: "string3,string4,string5,string6,string7" }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the `contentmodel` was set as `default` `property alias contentmodel: content.model` it is sufficient to put it, where it was placed. The `id` does not change a bit. I guess the problem is, that there are multiple, non-ListModel-Objects instantiated as `children` of `MyPage`, especially after the `ListModel` that would then overwrite the `ListModel`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, derM was correct, setting the default allowed this to work, but I feel it was a case of two mistakes canceling out.  I've removed the default tag and restructured it as Blabbouze recommended.  Turns out what was giving me issues was variable name conflicts elsewhere in the code, but this has helped me better structure these files